# Wordpress: Attachment Gallery only display 5 images

Tags: php, wordpress

I am pulling in all the attachment images for a page into a template, so that I can use a Jquery Galleriffic gallery on them.

The gallery works fine, but for some reason it is only displaying 5 thumbnails, this is not being controlled by the Galleriffic plugin, it is limiting the thumbnails before it gets to reading the Jquery file.

Here is the code for how I am pulling in the attachments:

```
<?php $images = get_posts("post_mime_type=image&post_type=attachment&orderby=menu_order ID&order=ASC&post_parent=$post->ID");  // we get array of images ?>


                            <?php if(!empty($images)) foreach($images as $img) : ?>
                                <li><a class="thumb" href="<?php echo array_shift( wp_get_attachment_image_src($img->ID,"large") ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo array_shift( wp_get_attachment_image_src($img->ID,"thumbnail") ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr($img->post_title); ?>" /></a></li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the default amount of posts returned is 5 (see also the [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts))

Try updating that.

So add `&numberposts=100` (for example 100 here)

ps: For the sake of readability make it an array as displayed on the docs linked above